# Conditional trait mixins

Tags: scala, traits

Say I have a class `A` that should be mixed in with trait `B`, where `B` should be either `B1` or `B2` based on a flag `b1`:

```
val b1: Boolean

type B = if (b1) B1 else B2 // impossible Scala code

class A extends B
```

Is there a way to "dynamically" mixin a trait based on a condition?

Answer (score 4):

Types are static things with definitions fixed at compile time. You can create instances of variant anonymous classes using if / else logic, though:

```
val a = if (b) new A with B1 else new A with B2
```

Comment: Is there any way I can inherit this to another class ie. `class C if (b) new A with B1 else new A with B2`?